# Get notification from Youtube API when a channel starts live?

Tags: javascript, notifications, youtube-api, live-streaming

Currently, I am making the java-script mobile app that plays live video from youtube. Suppose I have youtube url of upcoming live event, is there any way to get notification using Youtube API when that video is starting live. 
I've done some research, but cannot get any answer for my problem.

Thanks in advance for your helps.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately neither the YouTube API nor the YouTube Live streaming have any watch methods or notify methods.

You could try and add it as a feature request is a good idea [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:186600%2B)

Comment: See this (open) issue: [Add pubsub capability to notify when a channel goes live](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36124161)